# É possível afirmar que o esquema está normalizado em 3FN?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional, relacionamento, normalização

## Explicando o Contexto

Na [internet](https://www.estudegratis.com.br/questao-de-concurso/144475) encontrei um exemplo de um esquema descrito dessa forma:

> **conta**(num-conta, descr-conta, **lançamento**(num-lanc, tipolanc, data-lanc, valor-lanc)).

Perceba que do jeito que esse esquema está, ele não encontra-se normalizado.

Agora considere os seguintes critérios:

> 1. A **conta** e **lançamento** são grupos de ocorrência dos atributos entre parênteses e a eles justapostos;
> 2. Os atributos sublinhados são identificadores da relação à qual pertencem;
> 3. O `num-lanc` é dependente de `num-conta`, isto é, além de `num-lanc`, é necessário `num-conta` para identificar um lançamento específico;
> 4. **Não** é necessário guardar histórico, isto é, o surgimento de um par num-conta e num-lanc iguais a um já registrado, substitui o registro.

`Visto os critérios, agora devemos normalizar o esquema até a 3FN.`

### Uma alternativa possível

**conta**(num-conta, descr-conta) e **lançamento**(numconta, num-lanc, data-lanc, valor-lanc).

## Dúvida

Estaria o exemplo acima normalizado até 3FN?

Answer (score 3):

Bom vamos la... vendo esta alternativa possível que você mostra na pergunta, eu chego nessa conclusão...

Está em 1FN, pois todos os campos contém apenas valores atômicos e monovalorados, ou seja, não contém grupos de repetição.

Também está em 2FN, pois não existe atributo não chave que é dependente de somente uma parte da chave primária.

E está em 3FN também, pois não existe atributos não chave sendo dependentes de outros atributos não chave.

Então eu afirmaria que está em 3FN sim.